# Curious decomposition between two sets

Tags: co.combinatorics, set-theory

Suppose $X,Y$ are sets, and $f:X\to Y$ and $g: Y \to X$. Then there are disjoint subsets  $X_1,X_2 \subseteq X$ with $X_1\cup X_2= X$ and disjoint subsets $Y_1,Y_2 \subseteq Y$ with $Y_1\cup Y_2= Y$ such that

- $f(X_1) = Y_1$,  and
- $g(Y_2) = X_2$.

(This curious result is a consequence of the [Knaster-Tarski fixed point theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knaster%E2%80%93Tarski_theorem).)

Can this statement be generalized to partial functions, or even binary relations $R_1, R_2 \subseteq X\times Y$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I think the exact same proof goes through for binary relations $R: X \nrightarrow Y$ and $S: Y \nrightarrow X$ (which of course includes the partial function case). Each induces a monotone operation between power sets, e.g. $\exists R: PX \to PY$ takes $A \subseteq X$ to $\{y: \exists_{x \in A} R(x, y)\}$. Letting $\neg_X$ denote complementation on subsets $A \subseteq X$, we obtain a covariant (i.e. monotone) operation

$$\neg_X \circ \exists S \circ \neg_Y \circ \exists R: PX \to PX$$

which by the Knaster-Tarski theorem has a fixed point $X_1 \in PX$. Put $Y_1 = (\exists R)(X_1)$ and $Y_2 = \neg_Y Y_1$ and $X_2 = (\exists S)(Y_2)$. Then $X_2 = \neg_X X_1$ by the fixed point equation.

Comment: This answer is a gem (to my mind). @Todd Trimble. Existing methods are here efficiently brought to bear to answer the question in the OP. Some of the aspects of the answer will probably *not be appreciated* by some readers not experienced in category theory. Since there seems to be a discipline of 'art appreciation' to try save aspects of a work of art being lost on some, there should also be something like 'mathematics appreciation', so here I try to do this for some of the unexplained aspects of this answer. Firstly, $R\colon X \nrightarrow Y$ is [...]

Comment: [...] currently apparently only treats functions, not binary relations, so is not yet quite compatible with the above answer. It might improve the above answer to write $\exists_R$ instead of $\exists R$, which to some may read 'there exists $R$', while '$\exists_R$' also notationally suggests that something like 'exists-via-$R$' is meant. (Incidentally, knowing that that $\exists_f$ is firmly entrenched, if I were to choose I would write $\exists_f$ in the form $(f)\exists(-)$, making it even more look like '$f$-wise exists'.) Incidentally, [...]

Comment: [...] changing to this subscript notation would spare you a parenthesis-pair in '$(\exists R)(X_1)$' later on. 
Another small thing, in a solution as good as the above, where form is so important, the notation $\{y\colon\exists_{x\in A} R(x,y)\}$ in the current version seems not quite good enough for the answer, in particular if the suggestion to write $\exists_R$ in analogy with $\exists_f$ is adopted. At least according to how I learned set-theory (correct me if there is something essentially wrong here), [...]

Comment: [...]  the notation $\{x\colon \varphi (x,y_0,\dotsc,y_{n-1})\}$, where $\varphi(x,y_0,\dotsc,y_{n-1})$ is a first-order formula over the signature of ZF set-theory, denotes a *class*, and may or may not denote a *set*, and in order to make formally sure that one defines a set, one has to use the *axiom schema of separation* and in particular *use a set in before the colon*.
So in particular, currently $\{x\colon \varphi (x,y_0,\dotsc,y_{n-1})\}$ seems (to me) *improvable*, for the benefit of future readers, [...]

Comment: [...] in two \emph{minute} ways: first, $\exists_{x\in A} R(x,y)$ seems not to be a formula over the language of set-theory, whether here $R$ is interpreted set-theory-style to a subset of $X\times Y$, or interpreted  distributor-style to mean either the set $0$ or the set $1$, depending on whether $R$ relates $x$ with $Y$. Second, strictly speaking ZF does not allows subscripted '$\exists$', an issue exacerbated *if* the suggestion to write $\exists_R$ is adopted.
My suggestion of improvement (there may be something wrong with it) would be to write [...]

Comment: [...] to write $\{  y\in Y\colon \varphi(x)    \}$, where $\varphi(x):=\exists x\quad x\in A\wedge R(x,y)=1\qquad$ (S)

is even formally a formula of contemporary ZF set theory, and where I have used your distributor-point-of-view, by *not* writing $(x,y)\in R$, which would just be wrong, since you did not define $R$ to be a set, merely to be a *name* of a functor.
It seems to me that there is nothing wrong with the mixing of ZF and the distributor-notation in suggestion (S).
And perhaps one should then briefly point out to inexperienced readers [...]

Comment: [...] that the '$\exists$' in $\exists_R$ is simply a notation/name, in particular point out that in your solution '$R$' here is *not* the name of a set, while in the set-definition just given, it is the familiar existential quantifier from the (logic of) ZF. Finally, the last sentence "Then $X_2=\neg_X X_1$ by the fixed point equation." seems confusing to me: $X_2=\neg_X X_1$ holds by hypothesis/problem-statement, it seems (to me) that you meant "Then with $g:=\neg_X\circ\exists_S\colon PY\rightarrow PX$ the required properties hold.", or something like this.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, @PeterHeinig! Maybe you could put them in a separate answer for better readability and appreciation?

Comment: Dear @DominicvanderZypen: thanks for the comment. For multiple reasons I think it better not to made explicit, I think it better *neither* to write more on this here, *nor* to ask for permission to do so. Until something happens that makes it clear what is a good way to proceed here, I will simply *leave it like this*. If you have *mathematical questions* on this, I'll be happy to try to answer them. Just one small thing, [...]

Comment: [....]  thing which may have been not made clear enought: $R\colon X\nrightarrow Y$ is *not* just the same as the 'characteristic function of $X\times Y$ in the sense of set-theory', since $R$ here is (the name of) a functor with codomain $\mathsf{Set}$, and $\mathsf{Set}$ is not a set, so the functor $R\colon X\nrightarrow Y$ is not a function. (One may speculate that this is the reason for why this, very usual, stroked-arrow-notation was selected.)  Finally, as a recommendation: your mileage may vary, but I think distributors($=$profunctors$=$modules) are useful and worth learning.

Comment: @PeterHeinig - I completely understand, and want to thank you again for the insightful comments!

Comment: Just to correct the comment with unbearably-many typos (I won't multiply the comments, the typo-ridden one was *deleted*): 0,1 were switched, and $\exists_f$ was *accidentally* called 'preimage'; this  comment 'belongs' between 'is' and 'currently) : [...] *distributors* (=modules=profunctors), and is a notation, for 'functor Xop×Y→Set which takes (x,y) to the set 1 if (x,y)∈R, and else to the set 0. Here, of course X and Y are discrete categories, in particular, Xop≅X. The notation $∃R$ is similar to a notation $∃_f$ for "direct images" in the nLab article 'preimage', which regrettably [...]